# How to make ledger query using SELECT statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @AccountId int = 1152; 
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '10/1/2019';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '1/25/2020';

DECLARE @PreBalance int = (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Debit), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(Credit), 0) 
                           FROM GL_Voucher m 
                           INNER JOIN GL_Voucher_Item_Type d ON m.Id = d.GL_Voucher_Id
                           WHERE m.Date < @StartDate
                             AND d.L5_Id = @AccountId)

SELECT d.Date, d.debit AS Debit, d.Credit, @PreBalance AS Opening
FROM GL_Voucher_Item_Type d 
INNER JOIN GL_Voucher m ON d.GL_Voucher_Id = m.Id
INNER JOIN Level5 a ON d.L5_Id = a.Id
INNER JOIN Level4 l4 ON a.L4_Id = l4.Id
INNER JOIN Level3 l3 ON l4.L3_id = l3.Id
INNER JOIN Level2 l2 ON l3.L2_id = l2.Id
INNER JOIN Level1 l1 ON l2.L1_id = l1.Id
WHERE m.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
  AND d.L5_Id = @AccountId
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

This is the output of query:

[image]

I want to show balance column initially as Balance=@Prebalance then if credit then Balance=Balance-Credit and if debit then Balance=Balance+Debit

Comment: This can be done, but is very product specific. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59902013/edit) your post and tag the specific database that you're using. [Why should I tag my RDBMS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388760/5790584)

Comment: @EricBrandt MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select d.Date,@PreBalance as Balance,
case when d.Credit > 0 THEN @PreBalance - d.Credit 
     else debit+@PreBalance end as CreditOrDebitBalance
from GL_Voucher_Item_Type d 
INNER JOIN GL_Voucher m ON d.GL_Voucher_Id=m.Id
INNER JOIN Level5 a ON d.L5_Id=a.Id
INNER JOIN Level4 l4 ON a.L4_Id=l4.Id
INNER JOIN Level3 l3 ON l4.L3_id=l3.Id
INNER JOIN Level2 l2 ON l3.L2_id=l2.Id
INNER JOIN Level1 l1 ON l2.L1_id=l1.Id
WHERE m.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
AND d.L5_Id=@AccountId
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Please show us expected output so we can help further.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near '@CreditOrDebitBalance'.

Comment: Oops!! its typo. there should not be @ in front of CreditOrDebitBalance. I updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I'd calculate running totals of debits and credits using `SUM OVER`, then do the math.

This is untested, but should be pretty close to what you're looking for.

```
SELECT d.DATE
    ,d.debit AS Debit
    ,d.Credit
    ,@PreBalance 
     - SUM(d.debit) OVER (ORDER BY d.DATE) + SUM(d.Credit) OVER (ORDER BY d.DATE)
     AS Opening
FROM GL_Voucher_Item_Type d
INNER JOIN GL_Voucher m ON d.GL_Voucher_Id = m.Id
INNER JOIN Level5 a ON d.L5_Id = a.Id
INNER JOIN Level4 l4 ON a.L4_Id = l4.Id
INNER JOIN Level3 l3 ON l4.L3_id = l3.Id
INNER JOIN Level2 l2 ON l3.L2_id = l2.Id
INNER JOIN Level1 l1 ON l2.L1_id = l1.Id
WHERE m.DATE BETWEEN @StartDate
        AND @EndDate
    AND d.L5_Id = @AccountId
ORDER BY DATE ASC
```